# Regex \P{IsHan} does not work well in Java 8

Tags: java, regex, unicode, unicode-string

I want to remove all non-Chinese characters in a String, and  retain Chinese Characters.

Here is an example:

input -> `hi你好（）【】「」{}[]()`

output -> `你好`

First of all, I try to extract all Chinese characters and append each to a StringBuilder using the following code:

```
public static String extractAllChineseCharacters(String input){
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\p{IsHan}").matcher(input);
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    while(matcher.find()){
        output.append(input.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end()));
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

The code works well, but i want a more concise code.

Then i try to replace all non-Chinese character with "" using the following code

```
public static String replaceCharacters(String input){
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\P{IsHan}").matcher(input);
    return matcher.replaceAll("");
}
```

but the code doesn't work as i expect.

When the input is `hi你好（）【】「」{}[]()`,

the output is `??你好`

i enter the debug mode, and find out the output's charSequences is `\uD87E\uD84e你好`

i know that java adopt UTF-16 to store a codeunit in a char variable, so (U+2F825)is presents as a surrogate pair `\uD87E\uDC25` in charSequence,and (U+23300)is presents as `\uD84C\uDF00`

**My question is:**
the regex pattern "\p{IsHan}"can match \uD87E\uDC25 two chars as a Chinese character "",but the regex pattern "\P{IsHan}" can‘t precisely match non-Chinese character.Why is that so?

Can anyone give some help? Thanks in advance!

[image: debug]

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? This works for me in Java 17.

Comment: @Sweeper i am using java 8 ,so is it a problem relate to java version ?

Comment: Possibly. Java 8 is 8 years old now. How about updating?

Comment: Since extended grapheme clusters matching are supported since Java 9, I'd imagine this would work in Java 9+.

Comment: it's relate to business code of the company where i work for，so version transferring may not  happen recently.

Comment: @Sweeper but why does the regex "\p{IsHan}" works well in java8 ?

Comment: It may be related to this: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6609854 ... but I'm not convinced.

Comment: @StephenC enlightening comment, it may be a JDK's bug of java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

The use of `\p{IsHan}` works in Java 8 - see below. Perhaps the input is encoded is a way that makes the matching fail?

Regarding "The code works well, but I want a more concise code", rather than match what you *want*, match what you *don't* want and remove it:

```java
public static String extractAllChineseCharacters(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("\\P{IsHan}", "");
}
```

See [live demo running Java 8](https://ideone.com/lJvWn4).

FYI:

- `\p{IsHan}"` matches any Chinese character
- `\P{IsHan}"` matches any *non* Chinese character.

---

Test:

```
String input = "\uD87E\uDC25\uD84C\uDF00hi你好\uD83D\uDC4B（）【】「」{}[]()";
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\P{IsHan}", ""));
```

Output:

```
hi你好（）【】「」{}[]()
你好
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: my question is  "Why pattern \P{IsHan} does not work well in java8" instead of "How to process a String".

Comment: Your question asked *i want a more concise code*, so I provided that. The code runs fine in Java 8 - see [live demo](https://ideone.com/lJvWn4). I suspect you are pasting/entering the Chinese characters in the wrong encoding, perhaps UTF-16 or Windows-1252?

Comment: @Bohemian OT, but cherry picking a statement from the OP and disingenuously presenting it as the actual question that was asked is not a good look, especially for a moderator.